# how to extract 7z zip file using perl in linux

Tags: perl, 7zip

I have an example.7z zip file in the following location /aaa/bbb/ccc. i need to extract that zip file in the same location itself. i tried many methods but can't able to get the correct output. please help me out. Thanks in advance!

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError) ;
use IO::File ;
my $input = '/aaa/bbb/ccc/example.7z';
my $zip = (split(/\//, $input))[-1]; #to extract the example.7z
my $buffer = '/aaa/bbb/ccc/';
unzip $zip => \$buffer
       or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n"
```

I tried this method..This example.7z zip file contains three .BIN files. i Need to extract them. currently i dint get any output in that location.

Comment: What methods have you tried? What _output_ did you get? What do you consider the correct output?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the
[`Archive::SevenZip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::SevenZip)
module.

I came up with this code by reading the documentation and doing some experiments.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Archive::SevenZip;

my $ar = Archive::SevenZip->new(
    archivename => "YourArchive.7z",
    find        => 1,
);

for my $entry ( $ar->list ) {

    next unless $entry->{Attributes} =~ /^A/;

    my $target = join "/", "YourExtractedFolderName", $entry->basename;
    $ar->extractMember( $entry->fileName, $target );
}
```

All files are extracted to the root of the folder because I test whether  `$entry` is a file (`$entry->{'Attributes'}` is `A` for files and `D` for directories). Knowing this you can extract folders by modifying my code.

You should also check whether the archive exists, otherwise it will return an error.

Comment: What do you think `%$entry{'Attributes'}` does? I don't even know myself!

Comment: I couln't able to use this perl module.getting "Can't locate Archive/SevenZip.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Archive::SevenZip module)" error. Can u suggest some other perl module which achieve the correct output?

Comment: I also note that, at least on Windows, `$entry{'Attributes'}` looks like `A_ -rw-r--r--`

Comment: @keeru: You need to install it. There is no other option unless you want to run the `7z` utility directly.

Comment: I used `%$entry{Attributes}` to dereference the hash, but yeah, `$entry->{Attributes}` is better

Comment: I'm working on Windows, if I try to print `$entry->{Attributes}` for each `$entry` I got the output `DDAAAA` with the archive I used for testing my code.  I don't know how you got `A_`